# How to show char fields in Pivot view Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I use odoo 12.
I declare char & date field in pivot views, but it's not showed. 
Maybe I have a wrong code, or Pivot only show float field.

Anyone can explain that ?
Thank you

Comment: Please provide us your non working code ;-)

Comment: <field name="machine" type="row"/>

<field name="shift" type="col"/>

<field name="output_hfg" type="measure" string="Output" widget="integer"/>

<field name="product_id" type="measure"/>

Comment: hai @CZoellner, I still need the right code, product_id should show the name of product. But in Pivot it's no value.
Can u help me ? Thanks in advance sir